# Erlang: Is there a way to reload changed modules into an already running node with rebar?

Tags: erlang

The rebar build tool seems pretty cool, but is there a way to recompile AND reload files into a currently running node with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see a need to bring rebar into it.

I use [reloader.erl](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/src/reloader.erl) from the Mochiweb project.  Just build this module along with the rest of your program and call `reloader:start()` early in your app's initialization sequence.

After that call, any time a module in your program changes on disk, the reloader will replace the running copy automatically.